# How to show that the inverse and derivative of an algebraic function are still algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

let F(x,y) be a nonzero polynomial with two variables, we call a continuous function f algebraic if F(x,f(x))=0, now suppose that f is injective then how to show that it's inverse is also algebraic, and if f is a C^1 function then how to show that the derivative is also algebraic? according to my intuitive, I want to use implicit function theorem to tackle this problem and to find appropriate polynomials according to the derivative of the implicit function and it's inverse, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I would say that the current formulation is false, see for instance the polynomial $F(x,y)=x^3-y$ and the function $f(x)=x^3$. $f$ is $F$-algebraic, but neither its inverse $\sqrt[3]x$ nor its derivarive $3x^2$ are $F$-algebraic. I propose a continuous function $f$ to be algebraic if there is a polynomial $F(x,y)$ in two variables such that, for all $x$, $F(x,f(x))=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For the inverse, note that $F(f^{-1}(x),x)=0$, so take $G(x,y)=F(y,x)$.  For the derivative note that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x, f(x)) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x, f(x)) f’(x) = 0.$$ Now eliminate the variable $y$ (e.g. by using the resultant or a Gröbner basis) from the system $$ F(x, y)=0 \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x, y) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x, y) z = 0$$ to find a polynomial $G(x,z)$ such that $G(x,f’(x))=0$.

Comment: Hi,could you add some detail to the construction of G? thank you

Comment: For the example $F(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$ see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-1%2C+2+x+%2B+2+y+z%2C+y%29) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebner+basis%5B%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2-1%2C+2+x+%2B+2+y+z%7D%2C+%7By%2C+z%2C+x%7D%5D).